# Exception handling

Tags: ruby, exception

I want to add an exception handler. Within a class, I have number of methods and I want to add `begin rescue end` in all these methods. Instead of adding `begin rescue end` in all the methods, can I define it at a single place?

Comment: Your situation is not clear enough.

Comment: The handling is the same in call cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the error handling into a method and call it from all other methods.

```
class Foo
  def method1
    with_exception_handling do
      raise 'some error'
    end
  end

  def method2
    with_exception_handling do
      puts "normal execution"
    end
  end

  private
  def with_exception_handling(&block)
    begin
      block.call
    rescue => ex
      puts "caught exception: #{ex.message}"
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.method1
f.method2
# >> caught exception: some error
# >> normal execution
```

Answer (score 1):

I think generally it's not a good idea to have such broad exception handling as it increases the chance that hard to detect bugs slip through your tests and error logs. However if you have a very good use case, you can use `method_missing` to create an elegant way to rescue each method without changing the code in each method.

If your method is

```
my_object.my_method
```

You could use `method_missing` to allow the following syntax:

```
my_object.my_method_rescued
```

E.g appending `_rescued` to any method name will execute that method wrapped in your error handler.

This a VERY rough example, but it should give you an idea:

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
   raise 'error!!!'
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    if method_name.to_s.end_with? '_rescued' 
      rescue_wrapper(method_name[0..-9], *args)
    end
  end

  private
  def rescue_wrapper(method_name, *args)
    begin
      self.send(method_name, *args)
    rescue => e
      # Error handling code here...
    end
  end

end


my_object = MyClass.new
my_object.my_method_rescued # => Calls error handling code on error
my_ojbect.my_method # => Raises an exception on error
```

Comment: Or one could use some metaprogramming to wrap methods with error handling.